# How to remove significance stars from chart.correlation function

Tags: r, graphics, correlation

I'm using the performance analytics chart.correlation program for 13 variables. I want to remove the significance stars from the upper quadrant.

I have tried using the ... and then adding "stars = FALSE" and other combinations based on reading what dependencies this package uses. This is a basic question that if answered will teach myself and others how to properly look up dependencies and how to change them in R packages.

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
my_data <- mtcars[, c(1,3,4,5,6,7)]
chart.Correlation(my_data, histogram = TRUE, pch = 19)
```

As expected there are bright red stars for significant p-values. Any help in making them disappear is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code for `chart.Correlation` you can see that the stars are generated via `symnum()`.  You can create a copy of the function and comment this and the call to `text()` that places them out.

```
chart.Correlation.nostars <- function (R, histogram = TRUE, method = c("pearson", "kendall", 
                                          "spearman"), ...) 
{
  x = checkData(R, method = "matrix")
  if (missing(method)) 
    method = method[1]
  panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits = 2, prefix = "", 
                        use = "pairwise.complete.obs", method = "pearson", 
                        cex.cor, ...) {
    usr <- par("usr")
    on.exit(par(usr))
    par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
    r <- cor(x, y, use = use, method = method)
    txt <- format(c(r, 0.123456789), digits = digits)[1]
    txt <- paste(prefix, txt, sep = "")
    if (missing(cex.cor)) 
      cex <- 0.8/strwidth(txt)
    test <- cor.test(as.numeric(x), as.numeric(y), method = method)
    # Signif <- symnum(test$p.value, corr = FALSE, na = FALSE, 
    #                  cutpoints = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1), symbols = c("***", 
    #                                                                           "**", "*", ".", " "))
    text(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = cex * (abs(r) + 0.3)/1.3)
    # text(0.8, 0.8, Signif, cex = cex, col = 2)
  }
  f <- function(t) {
    dnorm(t, mean = mean(x), sd = sd.xts(x))
  }
  dotargs <- list(...)
  dotargs$method <- NULL
  rm(method)
  hist.panel = function(x, ... = NULL) {
    par(new = TRUE)
    hist(x, col = "light gray", probability = TRUE, 
         axes = FALSE, main = "", breaks = "FD")
    lines(density(x, na.rm = TRUE), col = "red", lwd = 1)
    rug(x)
  }
  if (histogram) 
    pairs(x, gap = 0, lower.panel = panel.smooth, upper.panel = panel.cor, 
          diag.panel = hist.panel)
  else pairs(x, gap = 0, lower.panel = panel.smooth, upper.panel = panel.cor)
}


chart.Correlation.nostars(my_data)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you that seems to work. Is this often how packages are modified, going to the actual code and customizing it? As opposed to calling some variable and then making it false/null?

Comment: There's no one size fits all answer to your question although adapting functions to better suit your needs is common.  In this case the function has no inbuilt argument to make the stars optional.  The plot is also generated using base graphics and there is no means to remove elements from these plots once created.  The only option in this case is to prevent them being placed on the plot in the first place.